# jQuery ajax script wont work with n number of forms from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a little problem with my AJAX jQuery script and n number of forms...To be more precise, PHP script generate N number of forms (form include one textarea and one button), and in head tag I included jquery script. Problem is that jquery work only for first form and not with others (second, third...). I needed to work with all forms...This is the code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitForm").click(function() {
        var text = $("#comment").val();
        var id = $("#id").val();

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "addcomment.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "t="+ text +"&id="+id,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                }

            });
    });
    }); 
</script>
```

And this is PHP code

```
for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
{
     echo "<div style='border: 1px solid black;'>

              <textarea id='comment'></textarea>
              <input type='hidden' id='id' value='".$id."'/>
              <input type='button' id='submitForm' value='Add Comment'>

              </div>";
}
```

What is problem???

Comment: IDs must be unique, use classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your PHP side you should change with something similar to this to ensure that all the html elements has a unique id.

```
for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
{
     echo "<div style='border: 1px solid black;'>

              <textarea id='comment".$i."'></textarea>
              <input type='hidden' id='id".$i."' value='".$id."'/>
              <input type='button' id='".$i."' class='submitForm' value='Add Comment'>

              </div>";
}
```

and change the Javascript with something similar to this to reflect the changes made on the php side

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submitForm").click(function() {
        var formNumber = $(this).attr("id"); // Get the form number that was clicked, the id attribute of the clicked button
        var text = $("#comment"+formNumber).val(); // Get the comment of that particular form
        var id = $("#id"+formNumber).val(); // get the id of that particula form

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "addcomment.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "t="+ text +"&id="+id,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                }

            });
    });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For every form you're creating you're using the same ID.

IDs must be unique and only appear once on the page.

You should use a class instead as suggested in the comments.

So more like this:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++): ?>
<div>
    <textarea class="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" class="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <input type="button" class="submitForm" value="Add Comment">
</div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

I'm not sure where your `$id` variable comes from.

Your JavaScript will need to be updated as well to work with this, I'd do something like this (elaborated so you can see what's going on):

```
$('.submitForm').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stops the default form action (if there is one)
    var $submitButton = $(this);
    var $div = $submitButton.parent(); // gets the div container
    var id = $div.find('.id').val();
    var text = $div.find('.comment').val();

    // now do your ajax
});
```

Comment: Hm...when I use classes and in jquery change #comment with .comment, I dont get values from textarea. With id input everythinkg is fine...

Comment: You'll need to change the way you get the values as well as listening for the submission.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that, or give me a link with some documentations?